# Add website and call with url-path

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

i want to create a second website in my magento system (1.9) and want to call this by www.example.com/second-shop. My first shop is available under www.example.com/

Is there any way to do this?
Atm it works just if i change the url to sub.example.com

---

hmm... My code looks like this:

```
$mageRunCode = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] : '';
if( $mageRunCode == 'haendler' ){
    $lang = substr(locale_accept_from_http($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']),0,2);    
    if( $lang != 'de' && $lang != 'ch' && $lang != 'at' ){
        #$mageRunCode = 'englisch';
    }
}
```

How can i set the storeview name or storeview id to call it?
Found just "website" id and "store" id but my languages handles on "storeview"

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

1) Create the sub-directory 'second-shop' under magento root
2) Copy the 'index.php' from magento root to 'second-shop'directory.
3) Update the constant 'MAGENTO_ROOT', specify the magento root path.
4) $mageRunCode with website code (created from the admin panel 'System' > 'Manage Stores').

Let me know if still experiencing any concern.

Answer (score 0):

```
Follow the following step:-
1. Add another website from admin panel.
2. Add a folder second-shop in Magento root and copy index.php into it.
3. Update MAGENTO_ROOT in index.php

    $path = str_replace("second-shop", "", getcwd());
    define('MAGENTO_ROOT', $path);

4. Above Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType); code add the below lines:-

    $mageRunCode = 'secondshop';
    $mageRunType = 'website';

This will allow you to access the required website path.
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont want to copy the filesystem. Looks like a wrong way.
Maybe check by login the usergroup of user in index.php an set the store manuelly